# Live css is not generating

Tags: php, css, wordpress

What wrong I'm doing here why live css is not working.

I took reference from here https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API but it didn't work for me

```
        //adding nav color controlller
         $wp_customize->add_section('nav_color',array(
           'title'    => __('Style Navigation','dgthemecustomizer'),
           'panel'    => 'DG_COLOR_STYLING',
           'prority'  => '10'
         ));

         $wp_customize->add_setting('nav_color',array(
              'default'   => '#FFFFFF',
              'transport' =>  'refresh'
         ));

         $wp_customize->add_control(
                new WP_Customize_Color_Control($wp_customize,'nav_color',array(
                    'label'      => __( 'Navigation Background', 'DG_theme_customizer' ),
                    'section'    => 'nav_color',
                    'settings'   => 'nav_color',
                  'context'    => 'Navigation Background'
              ))
          );

        //function for making custom style work

        function custom_color_scheme(){
        ?>
            <style type="text/css">
               header{
                 background: #<?php echo get_theme_mod('nav_color');  ?>;
               }
            </style>
        <?php  }

        add_action('wp_head', 'custom_color_scheme');
       ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `wp-color-picker-alpha.min.js` Download file from github and use it by wp_enque.
https://github.com/23r9i0/wp-color-picker-alpha/blob/master/src/wp-color-picker-alpha.js